# Does $\text{Span}(\{1, e^x, e^{2x}, . . . e^{nx}, . . .\})=C(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Does the set of functions $A = \{1, e^x, e^{2x}, . . . e^{nx}, . . .\}\subseteq C(\mathbb{R})$ span $C(\mathbb{R})$? Here $C(\mathbb{R})$ is
the vector space of all continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Will the answer change if we
consider $A$ as a subset of the vector space of all differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

I think the answer to the first question is no, and I think that $f(x)=2^x$ is a counterexample. I am not sure about the second question. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hint : are all functions smooth?

Comment: Is $x$ in this span?

Comment: Hint for yet another way to attack the problem: what can you say about $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)$ for any $f$ in the span?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Wonderful hint. I know that limit will be the coefficient corresponding to the vector $1$, but a function like $g(x)=x$ will not have any horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Is $e^{x/2}$ in this span? Is $e^{-x}$ in this span?

Comment: You could show that the larger set $\{e^{rx}:r\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is still linearly independent, by contradiction and using the derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The span of the functions $e^{nx}$, $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$, consists of the finite linear combinations of these functions, and not a single function more than that. In other words, it consists of the functions $x\mapsto p\bigl(e^x\bigr)$, with $p$ an arbitrary polynomial of one variable.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for reminding me! That has made the question trivial.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: What kind of bounded functions are spanned by those functions?

Answer (score 7):

The [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of a function in $\text{Span}(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x},\ldots)$ may only have simple poles at the non-negative integers, but 
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(2^{-x}\right) = \frac{1}{s+\log 2}$$
and $\log(2)$ is both positive and irrational, hence $2^{-x}\not\in \text{Span}(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x},\ldots)$. A similar argument applies to $\sin(x)$: we have $\mathcal{L}(\sin x)=\frac{1}{1+s^2}$ with simple poles at $\pm i\not\in\mathbb{R}$, from which $\sin(x)\not\in\text{Span}(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x},\ldots)$. In $\text{Span}(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x},\ldots)$ we don't even have the identity function, since the Laplace transform of $x$ has a *double* pole at the origin.

---

However, if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ with a sub-interval $I=[a,b]$ we get something interesting. If we consider a continuous (or differentiable) function $f(x)$ over $I$, we may define $g(x)=f(\log x)$ over the interval $J=[e^a,e^b]$. $g(x)$ is continuous over $J$, hence by the [Weierstrass approximation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html) there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n(x)$ uniformly convergent to $g(x)$ on $J$, and the sequence $p_n(e^x)\in\text{Span}(1,e^x,e^{2x},\ldots)$ provides a uniform approximation of $f(x)$ over $I$.
For instance, over the interval $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$ we have
$$ x\approx -\frac{11}{6}+3e^x-\frac{3}{2}e^{2x}+\frac{1}{3}e^{3x} $$

This proves that $\text{Span}(1,e^x,e^{2x},\ldots)$ is dense in $C([a,b])$.

Comment: Can't we just use that $e^x =1+x+x^2/2+..... $ to obtain all the polynomials used in the Weirstrass theorem?

Comment: @MSIS: how, exactly? No non-trivial linear combination of $1,e^x,e^{2x},\ldots$ *is* a polynomial, and to prove that, over a compact interval, a uniform approximation of a specific polynomial can be reached we need to prove that the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix is not zero, or to follow my substitution argument above, that I believe is really elementary.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the OP asks for the span and your answer concerns the "analytic span" (i.e., the closure of the span).  Of course, the way you construe the question is also natural and makes it more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

No, each of the functions in the set S  is Real-Analytic and Real-Analytic functions are closed under sums/ Linear combinations. Consider a non-Real-analytic function, e.g., a test function. At the point where the Taylor series converges to the value of the function for any combination in the set, the non-analytic function cannot be approximated as closely as needed in the Sup Norm, which I assume you are using.